# Request.URL shows another domain. How it is possible?

Tags: asp.net, security

I have a running website (based on ASP.NET MVC) on some domain, let's say `mydomain.com`

Yesterday I was looking into site access logs and I noticed very weird logs: inside it, I saw different domain!

Something like `anotherdomain.com/somePage`

And I saw exception text in **my log** saying that 404 - `anotherdomain.com/somePage` can't be found. It looks like somehow my code running on some other domain (Request.URL show different domain).

How it is possible? Does that means that someone somehow got access to my host (I running on Azure) and steal my binaries and deployed on another host? Or maybe my website opened from iframe?

I need to understand in order to determine whether I have a breach.

Comment: IIS can be configured to respond to any queries on port 80 or with specific domain names. If your configuration is the former, then if someone sets up their DNS records to point at your server, this would happen. I would advise setting the domain names in IIS explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I had to guess, I would bet that someone accidentally set their domain's DNS records to point at your server. You can check where the A record for the domain is pointed with [nslookup](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/nslookup-checking-dns-records-on-windows/) or `whois`from the command line. If they are in fact mis-configured, you should contact the site administrator to let them know. This kind of mis-configuration, while uncommon, can happen more frequently with cloud services due to the inherently transient nature of the servers and routes used.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually possible to make a GET request to access other domains, via your domain, to check if there's a badly configured proxy. Since you're not, it simply returns a 404 Not Found because you are not actually hosting those pages.

Scans like these happen all the time and is an unfortunate side effect of being connected to the internet, but does **not** mean that you are under attack or that someone has access to your host.